# Make divs scroll horizontally using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying making inline divs scroll horizontally by clicking on a toggle button, smoothly, but I don't know how to make this work : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7VdQ/8/)

Here is my code:

```
   <button class="go">go</button>

<div class="right">right scroll</div>
<div class="left">left scroll</div>
```

jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('.go').on('click', function(){
        $('.left').animate({'left': '-105%'});
        $('.right').animate({'left': '0px'});
        $(this).toggleClass('return go');
        $('.return').bind('click', function(){
        $('.left').animate({'left': '0px'});
        $('.right').animate({'left': '105%'});
        $(this).toggleClass('return go');
    });
    });
});
```

css

```
.left {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:300px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    left:0;
}
.right {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:300px;
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
    right:-105%;
     float:left;
    clear:right;

}
```

Comment: Please also add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: @bfavaretto ok but remove - 1 :/ please i putted jsfiddle

Comment: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: The -1 was not mine. The jsfiddle is not enough, who knows if they don't delete old fiddles, or if the service will still exist tomorrow? The idea of Stack Overflow is that your question should also be useful for future visitors, that's why code should go into the question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: @bfavaretto you're right i didn't thought about if they remove that :P

Comment: Seriously? 244 Questions, 3 gold badges, and you don't see if a post looks like a first timer?

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly it is you want to do. Do you want to scroll the parent (here it is `<body/>`) or move the `<div/>`s like you try to do in your jQuery code?

Comment: i want to show sliding the divs, left to right and right to left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
$(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        $('.left').animate({'left': '-105%'});
        $('.right').animate({'left': '0px'});
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f7VdQ/3/

You were not animating the elements, just setting their CSS. Also, you were setting another click handler on the link on every click (I didn't understand why, so I removed it).

---

**Regarding your updates/comments**

- To make the divs side-by-side, wrap them in an container with `position: relative`, and use `position: absolute` on the divs, with `top: 0`. Don't use floats.
- Don't set a new click handler from within the click handler. That doesn't replace the existing click handler, but adds a new one. So every click does more animations than the previous one (and the visible effect [in this case](http://jsfiddle.net/f7VdQ/6/) is a delay before the animation starts). Use an `if` statement inside you existing click handler instead:

  ```
  $('a').on('click', function(){
      if($('.left').css('left') == '0px') {
          $('.left').animate({'left': '-105%'});
          $('.right').animate({'left': '0px'});
      } else {
          $('.left').animate({'left': '0px'});
          $('.right').animate({'left': '105%'});
      };
  });
  ```

  **[`Working demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/f7VdQ/24/)**

Comment: this could be the fix, problem is divs are not inline :( and i have the same problem too :( i see divs 1 over the other instead of inline :P can you confirm? i'm on FF

Comment: That's because they're both taking the full available width (both have `min-width:100%;`). Make them 50% or less.

Comment: but they can be out of screen before to show them , i mean, uhmmmm really can't fix this actually , let me try somenthing more , then i'll tell you thanks a lot man!

Comment: this is what i would like to do http://jsfiddle.net/f7VdQ/6/ problem is div still being not inline :(

Comment: @okok See my update above, I think that's what you're looking for.